# flatMap doesn't work in yarn test javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, yarnpkg

I have some code in a component method of mine [using `flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap). The code works just fine in the browser, but the `flatMap` method isn't there when running the code using `yarn test`. Has anyone ever seen something like this before?

```
● Click Events › should copy table data

TypeError: children.map(...).flatMap is not a function

  181 |     const dataKeys = children
  182 |       .map(({ $: { data: dataKey } }) => dataKey)
> 183 |       .flatMap(k => k.split(LEVEL_DELIMITER));
      |        ^
```

EDIT - reproducible example: created a CRA base and added this simple test:

```
it('can flatMap', () => {
    [1, 2, 3, 4].flatMap(x => [x * 2]);
});
```

got the same error:

```
 FAIL  src/App.test.js
● can flatMap

TypeError: [1,2,3,4].flatMap is not a function

  at Object.<anonymous>.it (src/App.test.js:12:16)
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
  at Promise.resolve.then.el (node_modules/p-map/index.js:46:16)
      at <anonymous>
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

✓ renders without crashing (4ms)
✕ can flatMap
```

Comment: Are you running the tests on Node, or…?

Comment: Can you do a simple test in your setup where you just test flatMap?  ... like this: `[1, 2, 3, 4].flatMap(x => [x * 2])` Just to make sure that it is not something else (like the value from the previous chain etc)

Comment: yes, using yarn. my node version is `8.9.1`

Comment: What testing framework are you using?

Comment: I'm using `jest`. My coworker just found the reason this is happening. It is because `flatMap` is not supported by NodeJS --> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A coworker of mine found the solution. Apparently `flatMap` isn't supported by Node.js:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#Browser_compatibility

---

`flatMap` is now supported in node 11+ as said below, see the same link.

Comment: It seems the compatibility table got updated and now shows version 11.

Comment: Thank you! I had an error with `jest` because of `flatmap`. Upgrade node on my machine from `v10.15.1` to `v12.11.0` was the solution.

Answer (score 5):

For what it is worth, using a react polyfill package also worked for me. I can control my own local environment, but the build system I have to work with is more restricted and used by multiple teams.

npm package: `react-app-polyfill`

Usage:

```
// setupTests.js (jest)
// Using ie9 polyfills as the "kitchen sink" of polyfills
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie9';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
```

This works for Node v10.16.0, what I have currently.

Comment: Good addition to this q/a. polyfills are a good way to get around issues like this. It isn't always the browser that needs it! I actually did this myself before deciding to get rid of it and just write the code differently to avoid a dependency. :)